# undefined method `each' for Ransack::Search when using Active Admin and Elastic Search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, activeadmin

Hello I've been using the Elastic Search in my app using the Railcasts#306 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) as an example.

Everything was working fine until I installed the Active Admin gem. When I pass in a query in my shops#index page I get a following error:

undefined method `each' for Ransack::Search>:Ransack::Search

Any idea why is it using the Ransack gem (not Elastic Search) for searching?

Here are the code fragments related to searching:

Shop.rb:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base

  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  (...)

  end
```

shops_controller.rb

```
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @shops = Shop.search(params[:query], load:true)
    else
      @shops = Shop.all
    end
    respond_with(@shops)
  end
```

shops/index.html.erb

```
<%=form_tag shops_path, :method =>:get do %>
<p><%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, class: "button small success" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you use ElasticSearch and Ransack (wich is a dependency of ActiveAdmin) at the same Model.

Ransack has a protection for this case. You can search in Ransack with `search` and `ransack`, if the model has already a `search` method Ransack don't over write them.

You need to ensure that ElasticSearch is loaded before Ransack (ActiveAdmin), that should solve your problem and you can use your code like before adding ActiveAdmin.

The problem with the solution of @nicooga is, that it's use Ransack to search and not ElasticSearch.

**EDIT: This should be the best solution:**

If you use tire:

```
Shop.tire.search
```

([Source](https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/1016449cd5bcfd52853f1728452e26962c18790e/lib/tire/model/search.rb#L263))

If you use elasticsearch-ruby or elasticsearch-rails:

```
Shop.__elasticsearch__.search
```

([source](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#the-__elasticsearch__-proxy))

**UPDATE: ActiveAdmin has now a section in his [docs](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/14-gotchas.md#with-gems-that-provides-a-search-class-method-on-a-model) about this problem.**

Answer (score 1):

When you use ransack,

```
Shop.search(params[:query])
```

returns a `Ransack::Search` object, hence the "undefined method `each' for Ransack::Search`" error.
Change that to

```
@shops = Shop.search(params[:query], load:true).result
```

Comment: This don't solve the problem, it still use Ransack for search and not ElasticSearch

Comment: "undefined method 'each' for Ransack::Search" was the error, but the question was: "Any idea why is it using the Ransack gem (not Elastic Search) for searching?". You solve the error, but didn't answered the question.

Comment: this doesn't anwser the question

Comment: You all were right. @Alexander you should mark the other answer as accepted so I can delete this one.